# Insert Data ignoring contraints on Database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, validation, nullable

My application has a complex data-model with multiple tables having complex relationship. The UI takes care of validating user inputs. However, I have a requirement where the user will like to temporarily save his data (sort of, as a Draft) so that he could keep on making changes on it for some time till he is pleased. In such a case Validations need not be there as he may not enter some mandatory attributes right-away. While I can easily switch-off validations in such a case the NON NULL constraints and referential integrity on Database level would not allow me to do so.

What are the other plausible ways to do such a thing? Since there are so many tables involved I don't wish to dup0licate them to let user insert data in some make-shift tables till be finalizes his Draft.

Comment: Like David aldridge noted, you can use deferrable (initially deferred) contraints, which will check constraints on commit, but not sure if you want an open transaction against your db while the user ponders for some amount of time.  I would consider walking the user through the steps in order via some wizard, saving data on app side as you go, and at end inserting to db in correct order.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at deferrable constraints:

```
create table daa_delete_me (col1 number not null deferrable);

alter session set constraints = deferred;

insert into daa_delete_me values (null); -- succeeds

commit; -- fails

insert into daa_delete_me values (null);

update daa_delete_me set col1 = 1;

commit; -- succeeds
```

Comment: With deferrable constraints, it's helpful to note that a rollback will be issued automatically if the commit fails.

Comment: Yes that's true, but if the UI really does take care of the validation then that shouldn't work. Too many times I think developers rely on applications and do not apply database constraints, so this seems like a good compromise.